# How do I listen to previous songs on Pandora?

Tags: pandora, pandora-playlist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get Pandora to play a certain song?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5458/how-can-i-get-pandora-to-play-a-certain-song)

I just got Pandora and I'll listen to a song but If I want to listen to it again it won't let me play it so how do I get it back to the certain song?

Answer (score 5):

You can't get to specific songs.  It's a radio station and they select what to play.  You can influence the selections by liking or disliking selections, and that will tailor what future selections will be like, but you can't ask for a particular song like you can when you buy a song on a CD or on iTunes.